# SetTimeout issue in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I've the following code which runs fine under Chrome (V8) but fails inside node:

```
var id;
id = setTimeout("TimeoutHandler()", 10);
console.log ('SET');

function TimeoutHandler()
{
  clearTimeout(id);
  console.log ('CLEAR');
}
```

Chrome output:

```
SET 
CLEAR
```

Nodejs output:

```
SET
timers.js:110
    first._onTimeout();
          ^
TypeError: Property '_onTimeout' of object [object Object] is not a function
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Any ideas why?
Thanks

Comment: Interesting that NodeJS doesn't type-check the argument. It could provide a clearer error message if it did.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unlike in most browsers, `setTimeout` in node.js does not accept a string parameter.  You must pass it a function.  For example:

```
function TimeoutHandler()
{
  clearTimeout(id);
  console.log ('CLEAR');
}

var id;
id = setTimeout(TimeoutHandler, 10);
console.log ('SET');
```