# How can I setTimeout in express node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I fetch data from Database in Kinvey using 2 javascript functions. I want the first function to be executed, and the next call to wait 2 seconds before executing. Everytime I use setTimeout I get:
My error is :

```
TypeError: first._onTimeout is not a function
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

My code is this:

```
router.post('/datacol/getuserdata', (req, res) => {
  request(
    {
      url: kinveyurl + 'getPrivacyLevel',
      method: 'POST',
      json: {
        "user_id" : req.body.user,
        "sensors" : parseInt(req.body.sensor),
        "contexts": parseInt(req.body.context),
        "day_no"  : parseInt(req.body.day),
        "data_collectors": parseInt(req.user.type)
      },
      auth: {
        user: config.kinvey.appKey,
        pass: config.kinvey.masterSecret,
        sendImmediately: true
      }
    }, ( err, resp, bod) => {
    if(err) console.error(err)
    console.log("User " + req.body.user + " Summarization Level = " + bod.summarization_level)

    // This here should execute after 2 seconds!!!
    // I try to set the timeout here!!
    setTimeout(request(
      {
        url: kinveyurl + 'getAccelerometerData',
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
          "user_id" : req.body.user,
          "summarization_level": parseInt(bod.summarization_level),
          "day_no"  : parseInt(req.body.day)
        },
        auth: {
          user: config.kinvey.appKey,
          pass: config.kinvey.masterSecret,
          sendImmediately: true
        }
      }, ( err, resp, sensorData) => {
      if(err) console.error(err)
      console.log(sensorData)
      res.render('datacolaccelerometer', { user : req.user, sensordata: sensorData })
    }),3000);
  })
})
```

I am new to express and I do not know what to place where.
In short, I would like to know where I should place the setTimeout so I can defer the execution of my second call to the javascript function by 2 seconds, thank you!

Comment: Wrap your `request` call in a function. `setTimeout( function(){//your code here}, 3000 );`

Comment: can you show it using my code?

Comment: I am not very sure that's the real problem that's why not adding it as an answer. What I meant is, move your `request(){//rest of your code}`, inside the `function(){//paste the request code here}` call, as I mentioned in above comment.

Comment: I did that initially, did not work, any other suggestions?

Comment: What error did you get then? I think, you probably need to shift your code inside the `function(){}` first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467398/settimeout-issue-in-node-js